# MYSQL get count of each column where it equals a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I recently set up a MYSQL database connected to a form filled with checkboxes. If the checkbox was selected, it would insert into the associated column a value of '1'; otherwise, it would receive a value of '0'.

I'd like to eventually look at aggregate data from this form, and was wondering if there was any way I could use MYSQL to get a number for each column which would be equal to the number of rows that had a value of '1'.

I've tried variations of:

```
select count(*) from POLLDATA group by column_name
```

which was unsuccessful, and nothing else I can think of seems to make sense (admittedly, I'm not all too experienced in SQL).

I'd really like to avoid:

```
select count(*) from POLLDATA where column_1='1'
```

for each column (there close to 100 of them).
Is there any way to do this besides typing out a select count(*) statement for each column?

EDIT:

If it helps, the columns are 'artist1', 'artist2', ....'artist88', 'gender', 'age', 'city', 'state'. As I tried to explain below, I was hoping that I'd be able to do something like:

```
select sum(EACH_COLUMN) from POLLDATA where gender='Male', city='New York City';
```

(obviously EACH_COLUMN is bogus)

Comment: Show some sample data to be easier to help you

Comment: You want to do your counts based on ~100 different columns?

Comment: Hey, you changed the question after I answered below.

Comment: You have 100 columns? It sounds like there's something wrong with your design.

Comment: @Andrew, the form has a listing of a bunch of musical artists and is associated with some information about each user. My idea for the implementation was to have a column for each artists, so that when the form closed I could filter searches by all the other information (e.g. by using where gender='male'). I was looking to be able to easily compare the counts for all of the columns associated with the artists to see how they did in aggregate with a specific set of filters on my selection.

Comment: Still not entirely sure I understand your requirement, but the only approach I can think of is to use case statements, as Vishal suggested below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just looking for the sheer number of 1's in the columns, you could try…

```
select sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3) from POLLDATA
```

Comment: Sorry! I was trying to add some more information to be more helpful.

Comment: That would definitely work, thanks. I was hoping to avoid having to type that out for all 100 columns, but its entirely possible this is the best solution

Answer (score 40):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.your_column = '1' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS OneCount,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.your_column='0' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS ZeroCount
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Comment: That's an extremely verbose way to write `SUM(your_column)`. And he never asked for a count of rows with zero.

Comment: That's true, must have misunderstood. And it is verbose I know, seemed like a one off thing for OP, so went with it.

Comment: While it may not be exactly what the OP was looking for - it *DID* provide the answer for what I was looking for.  Thanks, Vishal!

Comment: This is a good way to sum on specific values in columns, such as `sum( 
    case
      when order_status = 4 then 1
      else 0
    end) 
  as completed
  sum(
    case 
      when order_status = 50 then 1
      else 0
    end)
  as cancelled`

Answer (score 6):

A slightly more compact notation than `SUM ( CASE WHEN ... ELSE END)` is `SUM( IF( expression ) )`.

For the askers example, this could look something like:

```sql
select
  count(*) as total,
  sum(if(gender = 'MALE', 1, 0)) as males,
  sum(if(gender = 'FEMALE', 1, 0)) as females,
  sum(if(city = 'New York City', 1, 0)) as newYorkResidents
from POLLDATA;
```

Example result:

```
+-------+-------+---------+------------------+
| total | males | females | newYorkResidents |
+-------+-------+---------+------------------+
|    42 |    23 |      19 |               42 |
+-------+-------+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

select count(*) from POLLDATA group by column_name

I dont think you want to do a count cause this will also count the records with a 0.

try

```
 select column_naam,sum(column_name) from POLLDATA group by column_name
```

or

```
select column_naam,count(*) from POLLDATA 
 where column_name <> 0 
 group by column_name
```

only adds the 0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strings why not store actual numbers, 1 or 0.

Then you could use the sql SUM function.

Comment: The data types are actually ints, if that's what you mean (quotes worked interchangeably in my selection queries so I went ahead and added them to my description, sorry for the confusion).

Answer (score 0):

When the query begins to be a little too complicated, maybe it's because you should think again about your database structure. But if you want to keep your table as it is, you could use a prepared statement that automatically calculates all the sums for you, without specifying every single column:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT ',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(', `column_name`, ') AS sum_', `column_name`)),
    ' FROM POLLDATA WHERE gender=? AND city=?')
FROM   `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE  `table_schema`=DATABASE() 
       AND `table_name`='POLLDATA'
       AND `column_name` LIKE 'artist%'
INTO @sql;

SET @gender := 'male';
SET @city := 'New York';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @gender, @city;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/826171/1).